# jquery add element to first child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple section with two buttons these elements are created dynamically, I want to append input to a first button using jquery.

Here is my solution

HTML

```
<div id="interactive-layers">
    <div class="go_back">Go back</div>
    <div buttonid="3" class="video-btns show" targetmovieid="4" starttime="2.44" endtime="8.36">
        <span class="label">Submit</span></div>
    <div buttonid="81" class="video-btns show" targetmovieid="undefined" starttime="2.44" endtime="8.36">
        <span class="label">undefined</span></div>
</div>
```

Js

```
 var getButons = $('.video-btns').attr('buttonid');
    var targetmovieid = $(videobtns).attr('targetmovieid');
    if(getButons == 81 && targetmovieid =='undefined'){
        var inputf = $("<input id='username' style='background: red' class='sync-element' starttime='3' endtime='6'></input>");
            inputf.appendTo('.video-btns');  
    }else{
        console.log('something is fucking wrong');
    }
```

Now when I run my app I get the following result

```
<div id="interactive-layers">
    <div class="go_back">Go back</div>
    <div buttonid="81" class="video-btns show" targetmovieid="4" starttime="2.44" endtime="8.36">
         <span class="label">Submit</span>
        <input id="username" style="background: red" class="sync-element" starttime="3" endtime="6">
    </div>
    <div buttonid="3" class="video-btns show" targetmovieid="undefined" starttime="2.44" endtime="8.36">
      <span class="label">undefined</span>
        <input id="username" style="background: red" class="sync-element" starttime="3" endtime="6">
    </div>
</div>
```

My code adds to both buttons I just want to add to the button with `buttonid=81`
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So unclear what you want

Comment: do this instead `var getButons = $('.video-btns')` then loop through the results `$.each(getButons)` checking the buttonid of each item.

Comment: What is `videobtns`?

Comment: @trincot class of a button?

Comment: @Tyddlywink can you show your solution via code?

Comment: You never give `videobtns` a value. It is undefined.

Comment: Code shown won't add anything since using attr() as getter only returns value of first element in collection and those attributes don't match on first one based on the `if()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.video-btns').each(function() {
    var getButons = $(this).attr('buttonid');
    var targetmovieid = $(this).attr('targetmovieid');
    if (getButons == 81 && targetmovieid == 'undefined') {
        var inputf = $("<input id='username' style='background: red' class='sync-element' starttime='3' endtime='6'></input>");
        inputf.appendTo(this);
    } else {
        console.log('something is fucking wrong');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you change your JS code to this:

```
$('.video-btns').each(function(key, value) {
    let buttonid = $(this).attr("buttonid");
  let targetmovieid = $(this).attr("targetmovieid");
  console.log(buttonid + ', ' + targetmovieid)
     if(buttonid == 81 && targetmovieid =='undefined'){
        var inputf = $("<input id='username' style='background: red' class='sync-element' starttime='3' endtime='6'></input>");
        inputf.appendTo($(this));  
    }
});
```

It will append the input to the buttons that meet your criteria by looping through them and getting those that match, @Tyddlywink mentions.

You could probably do some filtering or pass in some parameters for the buttonid and the targetmovieid to make it more generalized to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the `appendTo` to *all* elements with class `video-btns`, not just the one with the two attributes as specified in the `if` condition. Furthermore, when you get `attr()` of a jQuery collection, you get the result for the *first* element in that collection, not of *any* in that collection.

You can make your life easier by *selecting* immediately the button you need, including the conditions on the two attributes *in* the selector, using the square bracket notation:

```js
var $btn = $('.video-btns[buttonid=81][targetmovieid=undefined]');
if (!$btn.length) {
    console.log('something is very wrong');
} else {
    $btn.append($("<input>", { id: 'username', style: 'background: red', class: 'sync-element', starttime: 3, endtime: 6 }));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="interactive-layers">
    <div class="go_back">Go back</div>
    <div buttonid="3" class="video-btns show" targetmovieid="4" starttime="2.44" endtime="8.36">
        <span class="label">Submit</span></div>
    <div buttonid="81" class="video-btns show" targetmovieid="undefined" starttime="2.44" endtime="8.36">
        <span class="label">undefined</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/tyddlywink/6b2frvz8/

do this instead var getButons = $('.video-btns') then loop through the results $.each(getButons) checking the buttonid of each item.

```
<div id="interactive-layers">
  <div class="go_back">Go back</div>
  <div buttonid="3" class="video-btns show" targetmovieid="4" starttime="2.44" endtime="8.36">
    <span class="label">Submit</span></div>
  <div buttonid="81" class="video-btns show" targetmovieid="undefined" starttime="2.44" endtime="8.36">
    <span class="label">undefined</span></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var getButons = $('.video-btns');

  $.each(getButons, function() {

    var targetmovieid = $(this).attr('targetmovieid');

    if ($(this).attr("buttonid") == 81 && targetmovieid == 'undefined') {
      var inputf = $("<input id='username' style='background: red' class='sync-element' starttime='3' endtime='6'>  </input>");
      inputf.appendTo($(this));
    } else {
      console.log('something is Family Show wrong');
    }

  })



})
```

Answer (score -2):

You are appending the input to .video-btns class, and hence the element is getting added to both the buttons. Try appending using the Id instead of the class.

Edited:

```
var $btn = $('.video-btns');
$.each($btn, (index, currentBtn) => {
    if($(currentBtn).attr('buttonid') == '81' && $(currentBtn).attr('targetmovieid') == "undefined")
 { 
      $(currentBtn).append($("<input>", { id: 'username', style: 'background: red', class: 'sync-element', starttime: 3, endtime: 6 }));

  }
})
```